# How to read resulting JSON data into Java ?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read results of a JSON request into java, yet 
The partial output of my JSON request looks like this :

```
"route_summary": {
        "total_distance": 740,
        "total_time": 86,
        "start_point": "Marienstraße",
        "end_point": "Feldbergstraße"
    }
```

I would like to use the standard json library to extract the values in total_distance.
However I only seem to be able to get the 'route_summary' by doing this :

```
JSONObject json = null;
json = readJsonFromUrl(request);
json.get("route_summary");
```

Where

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

What I want is get 'into' route_summary, any clue / tip would be great !

Comment: you say "in-dept". Is the json string that you provided part of a larger json object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get `route_summary`, as you already did, and from that object you need to get the `total_distance`. This will give you back the `route_summary.total_distance`.

Code sample:

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
    int totalDistance = object.getJSONObject("route_summary").getInt("total_distance");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use GSON library. You can create class which will represent the message and then automatically map JSON to object by invoking function: `gson.fromJson(message, YourMessageClass.class).getRoute_summary()`.

Here is the example of such approach: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide/#TOC-Object-Examples

Comment: Why would you recommend using GSON? Is performance better? (I seem to be having functional JSON querries, hence don't see the difference)